# Where to ask for advice specific to the writing of scientific papers?

Tags: discussion, support

Where to ask a question about grammar or word usage specific to scientific papers ?

For a situation of the following type: I wrote a grammatically correct sentence but maybe it is unusual in a scientific paper so I need to find a more scientific sounding alternative.

Comment: The simplest practice is to write like your favorite scientific writer. If you don't have a favorite scientist, why do you want to write scientific papers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need an answer based on domain-specific knowledge, the best site to post your question is a site devoted to that domain. There are a number of SE sites which address [scientific subjects](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science).

If you can't find a suitable site, then this site **may** be able to help. There are a number of knowledgeable members of this community in a variety of subjects, but (for example) you'll find fewer psychologists than there will be on [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/).

You will need to couch your question in a way which is suitable for the site. On this site, we deal with problems of the English language, so won't necessarily understand or be able to provide exactly what you want, and you'll need to include more explanation than you might have to on a specialist site. However, some criteria are the same between all sites: you will definitely have to define what you mean by “more scientific sounding”, for example, in order that whichever community you ask can actually know what you want and how you will judge which answer to accept.

If you want experts in the relevant subject domain to answer, don't couch your question in such a way that it is simply migrated here!

Do thoroughly read the help pages of your chosen site, particularly to find what's [on-topic](/help/on-topic); and choose tags wisely, reading the help for each tag too. Some tags, like our [single-word-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-request) tag, have [quite extensive checklists](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) to help formulate questions.